# MacBook Core 2 Duo CPU goes to 85-90 degrees Celsius

Tags: macbook, cpu-usage, cooling

I was encoding some videos today on my MacBook and noticed the temperature goes to around 90 degrees with the fan spinning full speed.

Should I be worried? Is this normal? I was going to leave my laptop off for a day running this, but now I get a little worried...

I know that when playing games it can get this high too, but I don't know if I should leave it running this high for a day.

Comment: I don't know exact numbers for a Macbook, so I won't make this an answer, but that sounds pretty damned hot even for a max load.  I might be concerned if the idle temps aren't much lower...

Comment: idle temp are ok, they're about 60 in summer and 40-45 in winter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. For reference my MacBook Pro hits 103 C when under max load compressing video files for an extended period of time which is why the fans kick up. Once the load (and temperature) decreases the fans will lower their speed. If running it this warm, be sure to give the computer extra airflow if you want it to cool down faster. If the CPU/computer gets too warm it will clock down the CPU long before it shuts itself off to prevent overheating.

Comment: That's very helpful. I didn't know that they can undreclock the CPU automatically. Didn't happen with my 2004 pentium 4 laptop as it shuts down itself all the time.

Comment: I use a laptop stand. Does it increase airflow?

Comment: @the_great_monkey: Yes it increases airflow. If it was say on a pillow or a soft surface? That's not so good and the only time I've seen a computer actively downclock it's speed.

Comment: How do you check if the cpu is underclocking? Can I do it in iStat or activity monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Those are regular temperatures for my MacBook when I'm doing CPU intensive tasks so I would say that this is normal and you shouldn't be worried.